# First time programming in livewires module, How do I make a start page for my executable game?

Tags: python, livewires

I want my game to go to a title slide first and return to that slide when the character dies (its an asteroids clone) any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [pygame](http://www.pygame.org/) module. There are a number of [tutorials](http://www.pygame.org/wiki/tutorials) that will get you up running fairly quickly.

Example from [lecture 3](http://rene.f0o.com/mywiki/LectureThree#head-29aff5fadab0f965dab3db56700b955bc7a78ced) of "Python game programming" (first tutorial):

```
import pygame, sys,os
from pygame.locals import * 

pygame.init() 

window = pygame.display.set_mode((468, 60)) 
pygame.display.set_caption('Monkey Fever') 
screen = pygame.display.get_surface() 

monkey_head_file_name = os.path.join("data","chimp.bmp")

monkey_surface = pygame.image.load(monkey_head_file_name)

screen.blit(monkey_surface, (0,0)) 
pygame.display.flip() 

def input(events): 
   for event in events: 
      if event.type == QUIT: 
         sys.exit(0) 
      else: 
         print event 

while True: 
   input(pygame.event.get())
```